# Rails application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk with Puma fails - 502 errors on every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I just deployed a Rails app to Elastic Beanstalk, and every request is giving me a 502 error.

Here's the contents of /var/logs/nginx/error.log

```
2015/05/20 16:24:25 [warn] 1535#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2015/05/20 16:27:12 [crit] 1537#0: *20 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "POST /get HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:27:17 [crit] 1537#0: *20 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "POST /get HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:27:19 [crit] 1537#0: *20 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "POST /get HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:27:22 [crit] 1537#0: *16 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.44.210, server: _, request: "GET /datapoint?tickers=AAPL&datapoints=Ratings HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/datapoint?tickers=AAPL&datapoints=Ratings", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:27:27 [crit] 1537#0: *20 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "POST /get HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:27:32 [crit] 1537#0: *20 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "POST /get HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:28:53 [crit] 1537#0: *52 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "GET /datapoint?tickers=AAPL&datapoints=Ratings HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/datapoint?tickers=AAPL&datapoints=Ratings", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/05/20 16:30:47 [crit] 1537#0: *69 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.51.94, server: _, request: "POST /get HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get", host: "securities-api-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

I think puma is running -

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-135 nginx]$ ps aux | grep puma
root     23299  1.0  0.2  53008  1428 ?        Ss   16:38   0:00 su -s /bin/bash -c puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb webapp
webapp   23314  0.0  2.4  75764 14604 ?        Rsl  16:38   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb
ec2-user 23317  0.0  0.1 110284   844 pts/0    S+   16:38   0:00 grep puma
```

pumaconf.rb

```
directory '/var/app/current'
threads 8, 32
workers %x(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
bind 'unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock'
stdout_redirect '/var/log/puma/puma.log', '/var/log/puma/puma.log', true
daemonize false
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same error and adding these two lines to `config/puma.rb` fixed the problem:

```
bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
```

After this step I faced another error to add ENV values, which is very straight forward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get `No such device or address @ rb_sysopen - /var/run/puma/my_app.sock (Errno::ENXIO)` with this after starting puma on EB now...

Answer (score 6):

Sorry - Super late to the game. But I found this entry when searching for the same error message and could solve it differently.

I am trying to let a Rails 6.1.1 (currently latest and greatest) application run on AWS Beanstalk (Puma with Ruby 2.6), where I got the same error as described in this post: Nginx throwing above connection error / Puma seems not reactive (no entries in puma logs) / When SSHing into the machine it shows Puma is running (`initctl status puma` -> shows process ID).

After some days of research (and trying all above answers without success) - I switched to Passenger - but still same result. Researching the same problem for Passenger showed the proper solution:

Do not use the gem of the application server in production when you want to use the already provided application server of the AWS platform branch ("Puma with Ruby 2.6..." or "Passenger with Ruby 2.6...") (it somehow collides with the already installed version). Therefore in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0', groups: [:development, :test]
```

respectively:

```
gem "passenger", ">= 5.3.2", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler", groups: [:development, :test]
```

or use the AWS Beanstalk platform without already installed application server ("Ruby 2.6 running on...)

PS: Seems to be only a solution for higher Rails versions (my old Rails 5.1 app runs perfectly on the "Puma with Ruby 2.6" platform even with the gem "normally" installed.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. For last 5 hours, I was trying to deploy my Rails 6.1.3.2  application to the Beanstalk platform Ruby 2.6.7 and Puma and this was the only thing which helped. Thanks a ton Michael!

Comment: Worked from me using the platform 'Ruby 2.7.3 and Puma' also. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this was happening because of a Gem loading error. I was able to reproduce the error by connecting to the server with `eb ssh` and running `pumactl start`.

For me, the conflict was with the `nio4r` gem, although for others it was the `puma` gem. Setting it to the same version as the Elastic Beanstalk platform's gem fixed the error.

More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110462/1852005
and here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=957426

Comment: I had this same issue as well, setting nio4r in gemfile to `gem 'nio4r', '= 2.5.7'` fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Add a *Procfile*

with this content:

> web: puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/pumaconf.rb

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-platform-procfile.html

Comment: Thank you this saved me! After this I also had to update my gemfile to match their version of Puma which was 6.3.1.

Comment: @SabrinaLeggett, according to the docs, your version of Puma in your `Gemfile` can be different to EB's if you use this config instead: `web: bundle exec puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/pumaconf.rb`

Comment: In fact, I would recommend the `bundle exec` version  so you can guarantee you avoid any conflicts between EB's Puma (which changes) and your Gemfile's `nio4r` version. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110462/1852005 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092359/1852005

Answer (score 1):

Changing `config.force_ssl = true` to `false` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Where did you change that?

Comment: This would be in a config file for Rails. `config/environments/production.rb` or anywhere else you may be setting env specific settings. It can also be in application.rb

Answer (score 0):

This line in your logfile means, that you've configured your nginx incorrectly.

```
upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/get"
```

Actually nginx tries to use unix domain socket as HTTP url.

Can't say exactly what is wrong at your nginx config without it, but you should have something like this:

```
upstream backend {
  server backend1.example.com weight=5;
  server 127.0.0.1:8080       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  server unix:/tmp/backend3;

  server backup1.example.com  backup; 
}
```

You should also check out this nginx doc http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: Any idea where the nginx config is located?

Comment: I don't have experience with EBS, but usually nginx config is located at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

But I'd try to change `bind 'unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock'` to `bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:8080'` for example. It would be much easier

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin you'd be taking a performance hit by moving away from unix sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS doc mandates that puma gem be installed as part of your application.

Add the following to your Gemfile as appropriate:

```
group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Comment: I am still getting the [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472304/rails-elastic-beanstalk-connection-time-out-puma-server). Seems like request first go to nginx before puma in the time stamps. Dont know how to fix this

Comment: That's not true. You have the choice of providing your own `puma` gem, or using EB's provided one. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-platform-procfile.html

Answer (score 0):

The error `unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)` will also occur if Elastic Beanstalk cannot detect your Rails application root for whatever reason.  In my case, the issue was simply that I was zipping up my Rails application contents inside a subfolder.  Instead of creating the zip in the same directory as `app`, `bin`, `config`, `db`, etc., the application content were being created inside a subfolder called `<app_name>`.

The only hint was in the Elastic Beanstalk *Events* section where it had an Informational notification (not warning or error level) which said `Gemfile not detected. Custom gems will not be included.`

Hope this helps others; took many deployments to figure out this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using Elastic Beanstalk, it starts up `puma` by running a command very similar to this one (as you can see by running `ps`):

```sh
sudo su -s /bin/bash -c "puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb webapp"
```

Try running that command in your eb ssh console. If you get an error like the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735620/puma-undefined-local-variable-or-method-daemonize-error):

```
config/puma.rb:23:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `daemonize' for #<Puma::DSL:0x000055596fadb448> (NameError)
```

you have probably declared Puma 5.x in your Gemfile. The solution would be to use puma < 5.0, as it removed the `daemonize` method. Note that the configuration Elastic Beanstalk uses is not `config/puma.rb` but `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're missing any newly added ENV variables.

To add new Environment variables follow:

- `Elastic Beanstalk` >
- `Environments` >
- `<Your Environment>` >
- `Configuration` >
- `Software` >
- `EDIT`

Under `Environment properties` Add the new ENV variables

[image]