# Rails Elastic Beanstalk connection time out - puma server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I have searched over the web and stackoverflow but could not get this right.

I have a rails app and deployed to elastic beanstalk. The health is ok and green but the url is not working. It waits a little while and the page says connection time out.

when I type `eb open`
gives an error;

```
ERROR: OSError :: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

Could not figure out why this is happening.

When I `eb deploy`

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Application update in progress on 1 instance. 0 out of 1 instance completed (running for 4 seconds).
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

Can be a problem with load balancers? Where can I see if my database is created/migrated?

[image]

Here what I see error messages:

[image]

Gem file;

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'json',             '~> 1.8.2'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'


gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'fog-aws'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'    #it is added to new Rails applications by default.


gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
gem 'figaro'

gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
#gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
#//= require turbolinks TO ASSETS gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'wicked'
gem 'geocoder'
gem "mailboxer"
gem 'toastr-rails'

#gem "select2-rails"
gem 'jquery-cookie-rails'



group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Comment: Is your EC2 instance running?

Comment: and is your database created/migrated?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `config.force_ssl = true` to `false` fixed it for me