# Rails 6 Application deployment fails using Elastic Beanstalk - 502 errors

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma, ruby-on-rails-6

Trying to deploy my rails application to elastic beanstalk but I'm getting 502 errors. I'm running React on Rails and I've tried to follow this -> [Rails application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk with Puma fails - 502 errors on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355569/rails-application-deployed-on-elastic-beanstalk-with-puma-fails-502-errors-on) but no luck. Any ideas?

Here are the logs

**/var/logs/nginx/error.log**

```
2020/01/09 04:11:45 [warn] 3083#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2020/01/09 04:20:04 [crit] 3087#0: *108 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.44.209, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "staging5.q39956drtr.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2020/01/09 04:25:23 [crit] 3087#0: *185 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.44.209, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "staging5.q39956drtr.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2020/01/09 04:25:24 [crit] 3087#0: *185 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.44.209, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "staging5.q39956drtr.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://staging5.q39956drtr.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

**Puma**

```
healthd   2775  0.0  3.4 683640 34356 ?        Ssl  04:11   0:04 puma 2.11.1 (tcp://127.0.0.1:22221) [healthd]  
root      7841  1.5  0.2  58788  2612 ?        Ss   05:56   0:00 su -s /bin/bash -c bundle exec puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb webapp
webapp    7940 43.0  1.1  70180 11460 ?        Rs   05:56   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle exec puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb
root      7957  0.0  0.2 110516  2136 pts/0    S+   05:56   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

**pumaconf.rb**

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"

plugin :tmp_restart
```

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/eb-activity.log` and make sure there weren't other errors with your deployment?

Comment: Did you get passed this issue? im also facing the same one!

Comment: Any updates on this? Facing same issue here.