# Puma undefined local variable or method `daemonize' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

guys, I could not find the problem as below：

```sh
config/puma.rb:23:in `_load_from': undefined local variable or method `daemonize' for #<Puma::DSL:0x000055596fadb448> (NameError)
```

here is my `puma.rb`:

```
workers 1
threads 1, 6
daemonize true
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
tmp_dir = "#{app_dir}/tmp"
bind "unix:///#{tmp_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
pidfile "#{tmp_dir}/pids/server.pid"
state_path "#{tmp_dir}/pids/puma.state"
```

My env is:

```rb
OS: Ubtuntu 20.04LTS
Ruby: 2.7.2
Rails: 6.0
```

I hope some one can help me, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using puma 5.X? then deamonization was removed in order to use systemd/upstart/a process supervisor instead

https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/2170

And changelog:
https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/History.md#500--2020-09-17
`Daemonization has been removed without replacement.`

Answer (score 3):

if you are using puma > 5.0

Daemonization has been removed without replacement, for reference [click here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1983)

> You can alternatively use [puma-daemon](https://github.com/kigster/puma-daemon)

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'puma-daemon', require: false
gem 'puma',  '~> 5'
```

`/config/puma.rb`

```
require 'puma/daemon'
daemonize
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks.  We are running on an old machine that still uses `sudo service puma start/stop`

Answer (score 0):

As the answer from `nuaky` above. puma had remove the `daemonize` since version 5.x and did not give us another function any more.

So I did it use linux  command `nohup` to run puma as blow:

```rb
$ nohup puma > /tmp/null 2>&1 &
```

so, I hope you could learn it with me.